# How to save a file applied audio filters with The Amazing Audio Engine?

Tags: ios, objective-c, the-amazing-audio-engine

I'm using TAAE, to apply filters on an Audio file, this seems to be work. But now, how can I save that audio file.

Comment: Hey bro have you found a way to do this?

Comment: I'm interested too